# You must provide the action with either a Personal Access Token or the GitHub Token secret in order to deploy

Tags: github, deployment, token, github-actions

when I use GitHub Actions funciton,It report Build and Deploy error:

```
Run renzhaosy/hexo-deploy-action@master
  env:
    PERSONAL_TOKEN: 
    PUBLISH_REPOSITORY: dipinxian/dipinxian.github.io
    BRANCH: master
    PUBLISH_DIR: ./public
/usr/bin/docker run --name af96b4eeb7a6302a0a421582dce43236b880a1_a6e7e6 --label af96b4 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e PERSONAL_TOKEN -e PUBLISH_REPOSITORY -e BRANCH -e PUBLISH_DIR -e HOME -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/dipinxin.github.io/dipinxin.github.io":"/github/workspace" af96b4:eeb7a6302a0a421582dce43236b880a1
```

You must provide the action with either a Personal Access Token or the GitHub Token secret in order to deploy.

```
##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you generated the **Personal Access Token** through the link: https://github.com/settings/tokens copy it.

You have to navigate to:

`YOUR_REPOSITORY -> settings -> secrets -> New repositoty secret`

Add the *name* as **ACCESS_TOKEN** and paste the secret generated through Personal Access Token as *value*.

In your `.yml` file

```yaml
PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

or

```yaml
GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls try to add a security token , and use it in your workflow yaml file.
[image]